# Deploying running word count on Spark

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I have a problem deploying the running word count example for Spark Streaming.  I am trying to deploy the same file that is provided with Spark examples, but I want to build and deploy this specific example as a stand alone application.

My file looks like this:

```java
package test;

import scala.Tuple2;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.StorageLevels;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public final class JavaNetworkWordCount {
    private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: JavaNetworkWordCount <hostname> <port>");
            System.exit(1);
        }


        // Create the context with a 1 second batch size
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("JavaNetworkWordCount");
        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf,
                Durations.seconds(1));

        // Create a JavaReceiverInputDStream on target ip:port and count the
        // words in input stream of \n delimited text (eg. generated by 'nc')
        // Note that no duplication in storage level only for running locally.
        // Replication necessary in distributed scenario for fault tolerance.
        JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = ssc.socketTextStream(args[0],
                Integer.parseInt(args[1]), StorageLevels.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER);
        JavaDStream<String> words = lines
                .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
                    public Iterable<String> call(String x) {
                        return Lists.newArrayList(SPACE.split(x));
                    }
                });
        JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(
                new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
                    public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
                        return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
                    }
                }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
            public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
                return i1 + i2;
            }
        });

        wordCounts.print();
        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

And my POM looks like this:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>io.tester</groupId>
<artifactId>streamer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>streamer</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
    <spark.version>1.4.1</spark.version>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>



<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>test.JavaNetworkWordCount</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

The error that I get is:

```sh
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/Lists
```

I look through my jar that I built with maven.  It has a with-dependencies appended to it, but it doesn't seem to actually have any dependencies in it.  I run it via mvn assembly:single.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please provide how your are submitting the job... using spark-submit ??

Comment: ./bin/spark-submit --class io.tester.JavaNetworkWordCount --master local[2] /tmp/streamer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar localhost 9999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `maven-assembly-plugin` indicates

> If your project wants to package your artifact in an uber-jar, the assembly plugin provides only basic support. For more control, use the Maven Shade Plugin

you can try to use the `maven-shade-plugin`. Try to replace the `maven-assembly-plugin` plugin tag with:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <executions>
     <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
    <execution>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <transformers>
        <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <mainClass>test.JavaNetworkWordCount</mainClass>
        </transformer>
      </transformers>
    </configuration>
      </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This should hopefully create a fat jar containing all your dependencies.

Comment: Just tried this.  Didn't work.  I also tried the assembly plugin.  Also didn't work for me.  The with-dependencies jar gets built, but there are no dependencies in it.  Just my classes.  Could it have anything to do with Scala?  Also, is there a way to submit to Spark without having an executable jar? Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out.  I had two problems.  One, I didn't notice that I had the provided clause (stupid cut and paste error).  The second problem I had was that one of the dependencies pulled in was signed and I needed to explicitly exclude the signature files.  My end product that actually works looks like this in case someone else is having this problem:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>io.tester</groupId>
<artifactId>streamer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>streamer</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
    <spark.version>1.4.1</spark.version>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>

    </dependency>
</dependencies>



<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>io.tester.streamer.JavaNetworkWordCount</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```